# React material-ui withStyles on external file not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I took a look a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729702/how-to-set-material-ui-withstyle-style-on-an-external-file-in-react), but still did manage to get this to work.

The intention is to separate the styles from the component file in order to have a cleaner setup.

It works fine when there is no `theme` involved.

I did try several iterations, with or without wrapping `withStyles` in the 
styles.js files.

The particular example below will of course throw error

`TypeError: "theme.spacing is not a function"`

So I have created a file for the `css` as follows

styles.js

```
 import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default theme => ({
...
 textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
 }
 ...
});
```

Then on the component file:

login.js

```
import styles from './styles';
...
render() {
   const { classes } = this.props;
}
...
export default withCookies(withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Login))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

import { Component } from './component';
import { Styles } from './styles';


export const StyledContainer = withStyles(
    CStyles,
)(Component);
```

and in styles.ts

```
import { createStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

/**
 * Styles for Component
 */
export const Styles = (theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        '.className': {
            fontSize: 10,
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Which material-ui version are you using?

In `4.x` version, `theme.spacing` is a function:

```js
export interface Spacing {
  (): number;
  (value1: SpacingArgument): number;
  (value1: SpacingArgument, value2: SpacingArgument): string;
  (value1: SpacingArgument, value2: SpacingArgument, value3: SpacingArgument): string;
  (
    value1: SpacingArgument,
    value2: SpacingArgument,
    value3: SpacingArgument,
    value4: SpacingArgument,
  ): string;
}
```

but in `3.x`, `theme.spacing` is a object:

```js
export interface Spacing {
  unit: number;
}
```

Comment: using react material-ui v 4.0.1

Comment: So could you log or debug the value of `theme` and `theme.spacing`? It's weird, because `theme` is a function param, it should have nothing to do with the place where `styles` function defined.